# Run JavaScript only when the anchor tags exist

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a small piece of JavaScript below, to remove focus from my menu for accessibility purposes. However on page load the 'anchor links' do not exist and so the variable 'as' returns NULL.

I want the code to run only when the dropdownMenu anchor tags exist.

```
const dropdownMenu = document.querySelector('#progressive-nav-more-list');
const as = dropdownMenu.querySelectorAll('a');
const last = as[as.length - 1];

last.addEventListener('blur', () => {
  this.container.classList.remove('opened');
  this.more_list.classList.add('hidden');
  toggleAria(this.more_list, 'aria-expanded');
});
```

Comment: Check whether `as` is not null, and only then execute code.

Comment: You have 2 options. 1. If you know when `as` will exists (if it appears in reaction of user interaction or call from the server) run that code then. 2. If you don't know, you can run with `setInterval` and check when it exists. This approach is not recommended because of performance but if you don't have a choice..

Comment: Could you surrond in document.onreadystatechange ? document.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (document.readyState == "complete") {
const dropdownMenu = document.querySelector('#progressive-nav-more-list');
const as = dropdownMenu.querySelectorAll('a');
const last = as[as.length - 1];

last.addEventListener('blur', () => {
  this.container.classList.remove('opened');
  this.more_list.classList.add('hidden');
  toggleAria(this.more_list, 'aria-expanded');
});    }
}

Comment: "*on page load the 'anchor links' do not exist*" - so how are these elements being appended to the document, are you able to bind the event-handlers at the point of creation/addition?

Comment: This won't solve your issue, but note that `this` in your code will be the window, *not* the blurred element.  You should do `last.addEventListener('blur', function() { ... })`.

Comment: Hi @RickHitchcock - I've used 'this' because I want the menu to blur when the user tabs away from menu focus and back to some other place outside it. Something like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NZygbz

Comment: That code works because it uses regular functions instead of arrow functions.  Arrow functions don't change the context of `this`.  You need to use `function() {` instead of `() => {`

Comment: @RickHitchcock I see, thank you for explain to me. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you surrond in document.onreadystatechange ?

```
    document.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (document.readyState == "complete") {
          const dropdownMenu = document.querySelector('#progressive-nav-more-list');
          const as = dropdownMenu.querySelectorAll('a');
          const last = as[as.length - 1];

          last.addEventListener('blur', () => {
            this.container.classList.remove('opened');
            this.more_list.classList.add('hidden');
            toggleAria(this.more_list, 'aria-expanded');
          });    
       }
    }
```